# What are the risks with browser extension wallets such as MetaMask?

Tags: wallets, metamask

[MetaMask](https://metamask.io/) is a neat browser extension (for Google Chrome, Firefox, Opera, and the Brave browser) that is also an Ethereum wallet.

The code for MetaMask seems to be available [here at GitHub](https://github.com/MetaMask/metamask-extension).

Considering the security mechanisms available in Ethereum, what are the risks with using it as a wallet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The code for MetaMask or  seems to be available here at
>   GitHub.

If code is in github means product is safe & secure?. Well I wan to clarify 2 points:

1. Attacker will analise code, if there any loop holes in the code. Attacker will try to enter from that hole to hack. This is happening more frequent attacks in crypto world[major attacks using this way]. I am not against open source.
2. Good side every one know[transparency] whats going on inside product/tool.

As per @danfinlay Today, MetaMask is indeed a "hot" wallet, in that you use it on a computer connected to the internet. This is usually considered less secure, because if a machine is on the internet, it could be accessed remotely, and keys could be stolen.

For more details refer below links:
https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/6j7445/how_secure_is_metamask/
https://steemit.com/eos/@sandwich/how-to-move-from-metamask-to-myetherwallet
https://hackernoon.com/how-one-hacker-stole-thousands-of-dollars-worth-of-cryptocurrency-with-a-classic-code-injection-a3aba5d2bff0

Comment: I do agree with that being open source does not automatically make the code secure. Using it will still require trusting the developers as many users may not have the needed coding background (or time) to review the code to the needed degree of granularity. Thanks for the reddit link, it is informative.